# How do I plot this (x^3 - 2*x)^Ln[x]?

Tags: plotting, graphics, equation-solving

y=`(x^3 - 2*x)^Ln[x]`

I'm totally clueless. I tried with y=`e^(Ln[x] Ln[-2 x + x^3])` by Ln-ing on both sides but there is something I'm missing. Could this be somehow connected with other problem I have that Mathematica doesn't calculate to an exact number when I have Log or Ln [x] in the function?

Comment: `e` and `Ln` are not defined. A search in the documentation for `e` and then `Ln` will show you what you should be using.

Comment: HOW CAN I BE SO DUMB? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look what you get:

```
Table[(x^3 - 2 x)^Log[x], {x, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
{23.9206 - 33.4926 I, 1.52163 + 4.25002 I, -1.56727 + 1.16885 I, -1.27875 - 
  0.344258 I, -0.625532 - 0.901147 I, -0.0342845 - 1.00769 I, 
 0.426687 - 0.882703 I, 0.749933 - 0.632977 I, 0.938908 - 0.322649 I, 
 1. + 0. I}
```

You can plot the real and imaginary part:

```
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm[(x^3 - 2 x)^Log[x]], {x, 0.1, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: HOW CAN I BE SO DUMB? THANK YOU! VIELEN DANK REWIIIII

Comment: You are wellcome!